# Why does MVC HttpCookieCollection.Set update the request's cookies?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, cookies, web

I came upon this issue because I was interested in cookies that were present in an HttpRequest object, but *not* in the HttpResponse object. I was very confused that a cookie that my browser and Fiddler claimed were not in my request were present in my HttpRequest object. I found that an ActionFilterAttribute was setting the response's cookie. After stepping over Response.Cookies.Set I saw that Request.Cookies included the cookie that I added to the response. Long story short I decompiled the assembly and figured out that it was intentional.

My questions are:

1. I have ideas on how to solve it, but is there already an established way around this?
2. What was reasoning behind that decision? It seems very counterintuitive.

Comment: This behavior is intended (as you found out) and documented on the [`HttpResponse.Cookies` MSDN page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpresponse.cookies.aspx): "After you add a cookie by using the HttpResponse.Cookies collection, the cookie is immediately available in the HttpRequest.Cookies collection, even if the response has not been sent to the client." I don't have an authoritative answer on why that behavior is desired though.